Sum values ​from a column with conditions based on values ​from other columns in a table
In the spreadsheet "(ACOES) VALORES" I will place a function =QTDE([@ACÃO])
The QTDE function will look in the EXTRATO spreadsheet, the EXTRATO table, the TIPO column and in all cells with COMPRA, BONIFICACAO or SUBSCRICAO values
Where these values ​​were found, you will check the ATIVO column for values ​​that were equal to what you selected in the formula =QTDE([AÇÃO]), when you find identical values, you will sum the values ​​in the QTDE column of the EXTRATO table
I will place the function in the QTDE column, in the (ACOES) VALORES spreadsheet

Here is the EXTRATO table in the EXTRATO spreadsheet. With my current VBA function it is only adding the values ​​of the lines in yellow (4, 11, 9), see that some do not respect the conditions I want, giving me the value of 24 with the result.

Here is my current code:
Function QTDE(acao As String) As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim tipoCol As ListColumn
    Dim ativoCol As ListColumn
    Dim qtdeCol As ListColumn
    Dim totalQtde As Double
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EXTRATO")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("EXTRATO")
    
    Set tipoCol = tbl.ListColumns("TIPO")
    Set ativoCol = tbl.ListColumns("ATIVO")
    Set qtdeCol = tbl.ListColumns("QTDE")
    
    For Each cel In tipoCol.DataBodyRange
        If (cel.Value = "COMPRA" Or cel.Value = "BONIFICACAO" Or cel.Value = "SUBSCRICAO") And ativoCol.DataBodyRange(cel.Row).Value = acao Then
            totalQtde = totalQtde + qtdeCol.DataBodyRange.Cells(cel.Row).Value
        End If
    Next cel
    
    QTDE = totalQtde
End Function


If your table headers are on row 1 then the first cel.Row value is 2 but the qtdeCol.DataBodyRange.Cells(2) is on Row 3....  Better to loop using something like For i=1 to tipoCol.DataBodyRange.Cels.Count and use i to index into each column.

I updated it with the row number and column letter in the print

My comment still stands - you are not referencing cells on the same table row

Noted, thanks for the tip

From comment above - you need to ensure your references cells are all on the same row:
Function QTDE(acao As String) As Double
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tipoColRng As Range, ativoColRng As Range, qtdeColRng As Range
    Dim totalQtde As Double
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EXTRATO").ListObjects("EXTRATO")
        Set tipoColRng = .ListColumns("TIPO").DataBodyRange
        Set ativoColRng = .ListColumns("ATIVO").DataBodyRange
        Set qtdeColRng = .ListColumns("QTDE").DataBodyRange
    End With
    
    For i = 1 To tipoColRng.Cells.Count
        Select Case tipoColRng.Cells(i).Value
            Case "COMPRA", "BONIFICACAO", "SUBSCRICAO" 'tidier...
                If ativoColRng.Cells(i).Value = acao Then
                    totalQtde = totalQtde + qtdeColRng.Cells(i).Value
                End If
        End Select
    Next i
    QTDE = totalQtde
End Function


It worked! I updated the question showing where the header is, but your code already worked for me, many Thanks!

This function works with the For each cel loop and returns the expected result in my sample sheet as well. However i'd prefer the already accepted answer because of Select Case.
Function QTDE(acao As String) As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim tipoCol As ListColumn
    Dim ativoCol As ListColumn
    Dim qtdeCol As ListColumn
    Dim totalQtde As Double

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EXTRATO")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("EXTRATO")

    Set tipoCol = tbl.ListColumns("TIPO")
    Set ativoCol = tbl.ListColumns("ATIVO")
    Set qtdeCol = tbl.ListColumns("QTDE")

    For Each cel In tipoCol.DataBodyRange
        If (cel.Value = "COMPRA" Or cel.Value = "BONIFICACAO" 
           Or cel.Value = "SUBSCRICAO") And cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = acao 
        Then
            totalQtde = totalQtde + cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
        End If
    Next cel
    QTDE = totalQtde
End Function


Thanks!! Worked too, gonna take notes on your code
